Windows Server 2016 shuts down unexpectedly
I have windows server 2016 and in the past few days the server is shutting down it's self. I have manual power up the server and then it shuts down again ramdomly. I do have UPS which protects this Server and my other Servers as well,  so it is not a problem with the UPS. I did checked the event viewer on Windows Server 2016 and I did not see find any major problem. Welcome solutions or where to identify the problem.

Is Windows activated?

When I've seen this happen (only thing in the logs is "recovered from an unexpected shutdown") the problem has been the PSU in the computer itself. Consider replacing that as a relatively cheap diagnostic.

This is very likely a hardware issue.  Power Supply is a good suggestion above, but it may also be faulty switch, wiring between the power components, motherboard issue.  You said you don't see any major issues, so I'm guessing no random BSODs, that rules out things like RAM.

What does the host hardware management log say!

The server is back online replaced the PSU had failed thanks for the help
